# Нужна помощь в расшифровке строки (android + BouncyCastle)

Tags: android

помогите пожалуйста переделать код для шифрования строки под расшифровку. 
Я взял код отсюда:
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/security/des-with-cbc-example/

Вот сам код:

```
import java.security.Security;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {



  Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());



  byte[] input = "www.javaCODEgeeks.com".getBytes();

  byte[] keyBytes = new byte[]{0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, (byte) 0x89, (byte) 0xab, (byte) 0xcd,


(byte) 0xef};



  byte[] ivBytes = new byte[]{0x07, 0x06, 0x05, 0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00};


  SecretKeySpec pKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DES");

  IvParameterSpec ivectorSpecv = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);

  Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS7Padding", "BC");


  System.out.println("input : " + new String(input));


  // encryption pass


  c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pKey, ivectorSpecv);


  byte[] encr = new byte;


  int ctLen = c.update(input, 0, input.length, encr, 0);


  ctLen += c.doFinal(encr, ctLen);


  System.out.println("cipher: " + new String(encr).getBytes("UTF-8").toString() + " bytes: " + ctLen);


  // decryption pass


  c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pKey, ivectorSpecv);


  byte[] decrpt = new byte;


  int ptLen = c.update(encr, 0, ctLen, decrpt, 0);


  ptLen += c.doFinal(decrpt, ptLen);


  System.out.println("plain : " + new String(decrpt) + " bytes: " + ptLen);
    }
}
```

У меня есть строка, которую я получаю от клиента, пробовал ее переделать в байты, а потом передавать переменной encr, но выдавало ошибку.
Строку конвертировал так:

```
String s_ = "pve%a";
byte[] decrpt2 = Base64.decode(s_, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: `ivBytes`,`keyBytes` должен совпадать на обеих сторонах.

Comment: @NewView, это я понимаю, но не совсем понимаю, как сопоставить другие элементы

Comment: А их не следует сопоставлять, клиент кодирует, отдает вам `Б64` строку, вы раскодируете строку.. и всех дел. Взаимосвязь только в одинаковых ключах на обеих сторонах. `String s_ = "pve%a";` и вот это для меня загадочно.. по любому мало букв для DES блока.

Comment: Не берусь утверждать как там в андроиде, но `byte[] encr = new byte;` вот тут на выходе что у вас получиться? массив 0 длинны? правда? Надо размер указать `byte[] encr = new byte[1024];`